# Apostrophe for plural nouns

Tags: word-usage, apostrophe

How can I use apostrophe for plural nouns (especially when using US English)

1. Shareholde**r's** Equity
2. Shareholder**s'** Equity

Which one is correct ? 1 or 2 ?

Note:
I found [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69442/use-of-lone-apostrophe-for-plural) is very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the word is indeed plural then the apostrophe comes after the 's', ie. option (2) is correct.

If you were talking abut a single shareholder then you would use option (1).